# GUı programming in tkinter, when ı create a windows and input labe ı cant assign

Tags: python, tkinter

ı am new in tkinter. I want to multpily two inputs box. my codes are below. The problem is when i run it runs as x2*x2 but i want to x2*x1  how can ı fix this code it runs only one box

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x900+100+200")

root.title("Converter")
root.configure(background="grey")
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
def call_result15(rL,inputn):
  x1=inputn.get()
  x2=inputn.get()
  h=float(float(x1)*float(x2))
  rL.config(text="% f " % h)

  return
numberInput=tk.StringVar()
var=tk.StringVar()
input_label=tk.Label(root,text="x1",background="white",foreground="black")
input_entry=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=numberInput)
input_label.grid()
input_entry.grid()
numberInput2=tk.StringVar()
var2=tk.StringVar()
input_label=tk.Label(root,text="x2",background="white",foreground="black")
input_entry=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=numberInput2)
input_label.grid()
input_entry.grid()

 rlabel=tk.Label(root,text="h1",background="white",foreground="black")
 rlabel.grid()


call_result15=partial(call_result15,rlabel,numberInput2)



result_button.grid()



 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code with proper formatting (with the entire code block selected, press the `{}` button in the editor), don't show us a screenshot.

Comment: i did i apolizage

Comment: Thank you. I assume you have more code besides this that actually binds the `call_result15` callback to some `Button` or something? Or how is it actually getting run at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def call_result15(rL,inputn):
  x1=inputn.get()
  x2=inputn.get()
```

`x1` and `x2` are both read from the same supplied `inputn` parameter...

```
call_result15=partial(call_result15,rlabel,numberInput2)
```

which is bound here. So of course we multiply the value from `numberInput2` by itself.

You need to write the callback so it accepts (and uses) both inputs, and bind both of them in the `partial`.